# Matrices range relation with a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $m>n$ and $V,W\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ two full rank matrices such that $\det(W^T V) \neq 0$.

How to find $Q=Q^T>0$ (a symmetric positive definite matrix) such that $\operatorname{range}(W) = \operatorname{range}(QV)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take $Q=WW^T+I-V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T$. First, since $QV=WW^TV$ and $W^TV$ is invertible, $QV$ has the same range as $W$. Second, as $Q$ is the sum of the Gram matrix $WW^T$ and the orthogonal projection $I-V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T$, it is positive semidefinite.

Finally, if $x^TQx=0$, then $x^TWW^Tx=0$ and $x^T(I-V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T)x=0$. The latter equality implies that $x$ lies inside the range of $V$, so that $x=Vy$ for some vector $y$. The former equality thus implies that $y^TV^TWW^TVy=0$. As $W^TV$ is invertible, we must have $y=0$. Therefore $x=0$. Hence $Q$ is actually positive definite.

Comment: Thank you very much ! In order to stay in the spirit of projections do you agree we can write $Q = W(W^TW)^{-1}W^T +(I - V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T)$ that is the orthognal projection on $\operatorname{range}(W)$ plus  the orthognal projection on $\operatorname{range}(V)^\perp$ ?

Comment: @MisterDa Yes, you can take that $Q$. The proof is similar.

Comment: yes, I agree, the proof is the same but nevertheless i was afraid to miss something. Thank a lot for your help,.